Triggering a Tracking Event from a MailChimp Embedded Form
I am trying to fire an event from an Amazon tracking pixel from a mailchimp embedded form as seen here:
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-071822.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
  #mc_embed_signup {
    background: #fbf7e9;
    clear: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font: 14px GothamBook;
  }

  /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <h2>
        <center>ENTER NOW</center>
      </h2>
      <div class="indicates-required donut-day-indicates"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <label for="mce-PHONE">Phone Number  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
        <input type="text" name="PHONE" class="required" value="" id="mce-PHONE">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-MMERGE3">Zip Code  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE3" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE3">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
        <strong>Privacy Opt-In </strong>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[53][1]" id="mce-group[53]-53-0">
            <label for="mce-group[53]-53-0">I have read and agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy.</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_a3c00a7db1498338382f9ad0d_995edf65e2" tabindex="-1" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
        <center><input type="submit" value="Enter Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="c-btn c-btn--primary donut-day-btn">
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='zip';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->


I've found this function on another thead that listens for the response from the form of a successful submit:
  (function() {
    var eventName = 'DOMNodeInserted'; // Look for changes in the element
    var el = document.querySelector('#mce-success-response') || document;
    var useCapture = true;
    
    el.addEventListener(eventName, function( event ){
      window.dataLayer.push({
        "event" : "mailchimpSubmission" // push custom event to the data layer.
      })
    } , useCapture);
  })();

But am having problems integrating it properly into the embedded form and sending the event properly to the Amazon tag/event which uses the format: amzn("trackEvent", EVENT_NAME, ATTRIBUTE);
So in this case it would be:
amzn("trackEvent", SignUp, Yes);
Any input/advice would be appreciated.
Integrated the code into the form in the proper syntax but have not seen the outgoing response so I'm clearly configuring something improperly.
